# Missing values masked array correlation (numpy.ma)

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, missing-data

I am trying to use numpy.ma.corrcoef to calculate correlations in the presence of missing data.

According to the documentation:
Except for the handling of missing data this function does the same as `numpy.corrcoef`. For more details and examples, see `numpy.corrcoef`.

Here is a bivariate dataset, for which only the first and second points have data for both variables.

```
array([[ 0.00494576, -0.01331578],
   [-0.00146498, -0.01349548],
   [ 0.00430321,         nan],
   [-0.00937105,         nan],
   [        nan, -0.01356873],
   [        nan, -0.01375538],
   [        nan, -0.00277393],
   [        nan,  0.0082988 ],
   [        nan,  0.        ],
   [        nan,  0.00275103],
   [        nan,  0.00547947],
   [        nan, -0.01375538],
   [        nan,  0.0110194 ],
   [        nan, -0.00549452],
   [        nan,  0.01910017],
   [        nan, -0.02462505],
   [        nan, -0.01676017],
   [        nan,  0.0112046 ],
   [        nan,  0.01108045],
   [        nan,  0.01639381],
   [        nan,  0.01078178],
   [        nan, -0.01078178]])
```

When I cast this as a masked array (np.ma.masked_array(t,np.isnan(t)) where t is the array above) and run np.ma.corrcoef (with rowvar=False) on it the correlation between the variables is given as -86.52 (in absolute value, not percentage!). Whereas running np.corrcoef on the first two points alone produces a correlation of 1 (again absolute value). This latter value is what I think I should expect from the first operation according to the documentation.

My Python version (Enthought 64 bit PyLab on Mac OS X.6.8) information is below and I am using Numpy version 1.6.1.

Python 2.7.3 |EPD 7.3-1 (64-bit)| (default, Apr 12 2012, 11:14:05) 
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

Please advise on what I am missing here! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is probably a bug in numpy.ma.corrcoef (or to be more exact maybe in np.ma.extras._covhelper which I think does not propagate the mask correctly from one column to the other for just single array input, but maybe I was looking at the wrong place).

Use `np.ma.corrcoef(b[:,0], b[:,1])` and create a bug report... `np.ma.corrcoef(b[:,0], b[:,1])` gives the expected result so its a simple workaround until it is fixed.

Comment: Thank you, I take it you were able to reproduce this then; thanks for the workaround, but I don't think it will really help me as much as an upgrade of numpy (see below) since I need the correlation matrix for a set of seven variables of which only two were shown in the example above

Comment: I get the same answer yes, so assuming its wrong, this is a bug in numpy and it seems _not_ yet fixed in newer versions. The problem may cook down to mean being subtracted over all numbers, but in the next step they are not used anymore... (so anyways, would be good if you can write a bugreport)

Answer (score 0):

With `a` being your example array, I have :

```
In [1]: np.ma.corrcoef(a[:2])
Out[1]: 
masked_array(data =
 [[1.0 1.0]
 [1.0 1.0]],
             mask =
 [[False False]
 [False False]],
       fill_value = 1e+20)
```

I am using numpy version 1.6.2

Comment: Thank you; the version of numpy I use is 1.6.1, and I would like to know if you have any advice on an upgrade for Enthought PyLab which I use. I've downloaded version 1.6.2 but when I try to install it, I get a message that says Python 2.7 is necessary. My Enthought copy is version 2.7.3 but my default version is 2.6 and it is this that the numpy installation seems to pick up on. How do I upgrade the Enthought installation please?